Query for partition on Ignite
Is there any way to query for data on a particular partition? For example, select only the entities of an Ignite's partition number 1 of 1024.
The only way that I found is manually query all keys, and using the Affinity object to get the partition where the entity belongs, and filter, but this is slow.
Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use a scan query with a specified partition.
Please take a look at the following links:
Using Cache Queries
Creating partition scan query returning all entries for given partition
